# Loop with If condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print a number of sheets in a workbook, but only if a cell has Print on that sheet in a certain cell. I cant get the loop to work through the tabs and stopping at the last one. here are a few attemps

1) **checking 1st tab, then moving on to next - but how do I end the loop at the final sheet? same name on sheet all the time**

```
Worksheets("name of 1st worksheet").Activate  
If Range("I6") = "Print" Then
Range("a1:h16").PrintOut
End If    
Do
ActiveSheet.Next.Activate

If Range("I6") = "Print" Then
 Range("a1:h16").PrintOut
 End If

 Loop
```

**2) ('attempting to choose sheet 8-45)** 
     Dim i As Long
    For i = 8 To 45
    If Range("I6") = "Print" Then
    End If

Comment: No need to use activate, use the worksheets collection

Answer (score 4):

Use a `For Each` loop to efficiently iterate all items in an object collection. The `Worksheets` collection only contains `Worksheet` objects, so prefer it over the `Sheets` collection, which can contain charts and other sheet types that don't have a `Range` member:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopAndPrint()
    Dim ws As Worksheet        
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("I6") = "Print" Then
            ws.Range("A1:H6").PrintOut
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I was going to comment about why I upvoted this answer, but seeing that the explanation actually fit better in the answer itself I went ahead and edited it in - hope you don't mind =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon np, the detail is better in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

***UNTESTED***:

```
Sub LoopSheets()
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(i)
            If .Range("I6") = "Print" Then .Range("a1:h16").PrintOut
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```